# Laravel: Using "LIKE" in where clauses

Tags: laravel

I am writing a query and I'm reading on the usage of "like" but I don't understand the difference of where the `%` goes.  In these 3, what are the differences?

```
 $items = NewItem::where('name', 'like', '%SPECIAL')->get();

 $items = NewItem::where('name', 'like', 'SPECIAL%')->get();

 $items = NewItem::where('name', 'like', '%SPECIAL%')->get();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO .... `%` this symbol act ad wildcard in `sql`  so `%special%` means `specal` before and after anything can be get   https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: There are two wildcards often used in conjunction with the LIKE operator:

% - The percent sign represents zero, one, or multiple characters
_ - The underscore represents a single character

Answer (score 1):

```
// % in first character, indicate that any word occurance in front are factored in and followed by the word next (SPECIAL)
// for example, "I AM SPECIAL", 
$items = NewItem::where('name', 'like', '%SPECIAL')->get();

// % in last character, indicate that any word occurance after the word (SPECIAL) are factored in
// for example, "SPECIAL IS ME", 
$items = NewItem::where('name', 'like', 'SPECIAL%')->get();

// % in both first and last, indicate that the word can be placed anywhere in the string, as long as the word "SPECIAL" existed, it considered true statement
// for example, "I AM SPECIAL", "SPECIAL", "SPECIAL IS ME", "You are SPECIAL and does she"
$items = NewItem::where('name', 'like', '%SPECIAL%')->get();
```